# Measuring request time in filter

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I'd like to measure request time in my filter. I've seen somewhere here, on stack something like this:

```
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
```

Sorry, but I don't remember the topic name and I can't find it now. It's my code but it shows me 0. Is there any other way to measure time request?

Comment: Is your filter not the deepest one so the chain would do nothing thus resulting in 0?

Comment: @fluffy
It's the only one filter, so I guess you're right